# Change folder to fetch on filemanager

Tags: php, fetch, file-manager

I've the following problem: i'm working on a filemanager consisting in only one index.php file, that fetches all the files and folders from the actual folder there its located in.

So if i have a folder with the filemanager file on it:

```
Folder01
 -folder-A
 -folder-B
 -file1.php
 -image.png
 -index.php
```

The filemanager will show: folder-A, folder-B, file1.php and image.png

The problem is I can't change the folder to fetch it's content, to be able to view, by default, the content of folder-A for example.

```php
$file = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ? urldecode($_REQUEST['file']) : '.';
if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'list') {
    if (is_dir($file)) {
        $directory = $file;
        $result = array();
        $files = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('.','..'));
        foreach($files as $entry) if($entry !== basename(__FILE__)) {
            $i = $directory . '/' . $entry;
            $stat = stat($i);
            $result[] = array(
                'mtime' => $stat['mtime'],
                'size' => $stat['size'],
                'name' => basename($i),
                'path' => preg_replace('@^\./@', '', $i),
                'ext' => pathinfo($i, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
                'is_dir' => is_dir($i),
                'is_deleteable' => (!is_dir($i) && is_writable($directory)) || 
                                   (is_dir($i) && is_writable($directory) && is_recursively_deleteable($i)),
                'is_readable' => is_readable($i),
                'is_writable' => is_writable($i),
                'is_executable' => is_executable($i),
            );
        }
    } else {
        err(412,"Not a Directory");
    }
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'is_writable' => is_writable($file), 'results' =>$result));
    exit;
}
```

This snippet is the beginning of its php code, which is in charge of fetching the files of the selected folder.

Any idea about how to change that?

Comment: *"The problem is when i try to change the folder"* - What problem? What is the actual problem?

Comment: Sorry! Forgot the most important part, the problem is that I can't change the folder to fetch it's content. I want to fetch the content from a folder called "Uploads".

Answer (score 0):

try glob function, its like dir command in dos,
it will list all of the dirs and files in the current working directory and put them in an array, which is the return value of the function.